# Make ceph minimize spread of file parts over OSDs

Tags: storage, ceph

I am considering an option of ceph as distributed filesystem for my home-made MAID (massive array of idle drives).

As far as I understand, Ceph oriented for cluster use and spread data evenly over OSDs (with respect to CRUSH maps) and tries to utilize parallelism of read operations over different nodes.

In my case I don't need to maximize spread and throughput, in ideal case it should fill first N OSDs (where N is replication factor) and only then start filling next N OSDs, to minimize amount of required active drives for adjacent data retrieval.

Can I somehow achieve such behaviour by tweaking placement groups count and CRUSH maps?
Or if it is not possible can I at least make ceph stop splitting files into more than one block?

Comment: From my experience, I don't think Ceph cannot do this (although I never actually tried, but I can't imagine how you would achieve that). It was designed as being a distributed object storage, not something else. As far as I can tell, you are not really looking for something distributed? I would point you to a much simpler solution such as thin allocated LVM which kind of does something like what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for something distributed, because HDDs will be on different machines in the network. I could use LVM over NBD, but it is not as flexible as ceph storage, in case that i still should introduce some fs over LVM block, so if i will add or remove HDDs from system it will lead to some mess with fs resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think something similar to what you want to achieve is possible with ceph. As far as I understand, ceph is a [distributed file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_file_system#Distributed_file_systems) and that it ensures high fault tolerance by using replication. Read here:

[Ceph aims primarily to be completely distributed without a single point of failure, scalable to the exabyte level, and freely available.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceph_%28software%29)

ceph's power is it's scalability and high availability:

> [Scalability and High Availability](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/architecture/)
>
> In traditional architectures, clients talk to a centralized component
> (e.g., a gateway, broker, API, facade, etc.), which acts as a single
> point of entry to a complex subsystem. This imposes a limit to both
> performance and scalability, while introducing a single point of
> failure (i.e., if the centralized component goes down, the whole
> system goes down, too).
>
> Ceph eliminates the centralized gateway to enable clients to interact
> with Ceph OSD Daemons directly. Ceph OSD Daemons create object
> replicas on other Ceph Nodes to ensure data safety and high
> availability. Ceph also uses a cluster of monitors to ensure high
> availability. To eliminate centralization, Ceph uses an algorithm
> called CRUSH.

What I'm trying to point out is that, ceph is made to take care of the physical disk's usage in a cluster environment in a way to ensure more resilience, high availability and transparency. Not quiet what you are looking for.

If you are worried about performance or disk I/O, there is this option called **Primary Affinity**, which can be employed, for example to prioritze SAAS disks over SATA. Read more [here](http://www.sebastien-han.fr/blog/2015/08/06/ceph-get-the-best-of-your-ssd-with-primary-affinity/) and [here](http://cephnotes.ksperis.com/blog/2014/08/20/ceph-primary-affinity).

> Primary Affinity
>
> When a Ceph Client reads or writes data, it always contacts the
> primary OSD in the acting set. For set [2, 3, 4], osd.2 is the
> primary. Sometimes an OSD isn’t well suited to act as a primary
> compared to other OSDs (e.g., it has a slow disk or a slow
> controller). To prevent performance bottlenecks (especially on read
> operations) while maximizing utilization of your hardware, you can set
> a Ceph OSD’s primary affinity so that CRUSH is less likely to use the
> OSD as a primary in an acting set.

```
ceph osd primary-affinity <osd-id> <weight>
```

> Primary affinity is 1 by default (i.e., an OSD may act as a primary).
> You may set the OSD primary range from 0-1, where 0 means that the OSD
> may NOT be used as a primary and 1 means that an OSD may be used as a
> primary. When the weight is < 1, it is less likely that CRUSH will
> select the Ceph OSD Daemon to act as a primary.

*I know this doesn't exactly answer all your questions, but may be provide some food for thought.*

See details here: http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/rados/operations/crush-map/#primary-affinity

And [here](http://karan-mj.blogspot.de/2014/01/how-data-is-stored-in-ceph-cluster.html) is nice blog explaining the ceph cluster.

Comment: will it access second osd if first will be full? Or this OSDs set is calculated for each object individualy?

Comment: No it wont. This more to improve performance. See my updated answer.